# How to make DPFBannerView in UITableview did not scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll, admob

i am new in Google admob development. In this case i need to add an admob inside my uitableview, I make an implementation like this on :

[image]

the problem is, the cell that contain the ads (I Use DFPBannerView) is scrollable, i want to make it unscrollable. I just want to make the uitableview scrollable but the banner view is not. I already implement some suggestion from [UIScrollView doesn't scroll when touching GADBannerView subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475059/uiscrollview-doesnt-scroll-when-touching-gadbannerview-subview/10274683#10274683)

but it still can not make the ads unscrollable. is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basic 2 solutions to this:

1. Add the view to the superview of your table view instead of to the table view itself. Then you just set the frame of the tableview to be shorter so that it is not cut off by the banner. This is provided you are not using a `UITableViewController` because if you're using one of those, the table view is the root view.
2. Add the subview to your tableview directly, and implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` and change its frame based on that. The implementation would look something like this:

   ```
   - (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
   {
       CGRect bannerFrame = myBanner.frame;
       bannerFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(scrollView.bounds) - bannerFrame.size.height;
       myBanner.frame = bannerFrame;
   }
   ```